# How to perform ranking based on several conditions?

Tags: excel, sorting, rank

```
Student Total   Result  GPC
A   398 PASS    1.2
B   341 PASS    1.6
C   396 PASS    1.8
D   402 FAIL    1.6
```

Let's say I have a table as above and I would like to perform sorting/ranking based on the following conditions:

1. Sort by "Result" descending
2. Then sort by "GPC" ascending
3. Finally sort by "Total" descending

Hence the end result would be like this:

```
Student Ranking
A   1
B   2
C   3
D   4
```

How can I do the sorting above in excel? I had tried to use RANK in the formula but it can only cater to one condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a number of intermediate columns to calculate a rank order number based on your sort rules

Results

[image: Results]

Formulas

[image]

Method
Column G: convert PASS/FAIL to a number (other functions require numeric data)
Column H..J: sort the data, a column for each of Total, Result, GPC
Column L..N: Rank the individual results
Column O: Combine individual rankings into single value for final ranking

**EDIT**

Here's as smaller version of the same method

[image: Results]

[image: Formulas]

Comment: Thanks Chris! it works flawlessly. What happens the records are growing? Does that mean I need to modify H1 formula accordingly?

Comment: Hi Chris,

The following data does not work well with your suggested formula:
Student Total   Result  GPC
A   362 PASS    1.4
B   402 FAIL    1.6
C   365 PASS    1.4
D   468 PASS    1.4

The ranking produced are as follow:
A 1
B 4
C 2
D 3

I am expecting:
A 3
B 4
C 2
D 1

Comment: Okay - I had managed to sort it. The last RANK should be in descending. Hence it should be using 0 instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

You've pretty much answered your own, very simple, question.  Using Excel's Sort dialog (Data>Sort) do the following:

1. Sort by "Result" descending
2. Then sort by "GPC" ascending
3. Finally sort by "Total" descending

You now have a sorted list.  Enter the numbers 1 through whatever starting in row 2 in the column of your choice and your list will be ranked.  Based on your question I can't see it being more complicated than that.

Comment: thanks, but I have to use a formula to sort it. How do I do that? Furthermore, Data > Sort does not work well when there are merged headers.

Comment: Merged cells are evil.  Use Center Across Selection instead if possible.  Or you could always omit row 1 from the sort and uncheck "my data has headers" in the Sort dialog.

Comment: I tried to get a single-cell formula, but it's ugly.  I'd go with Chris's approach of intermediate columns to keep it sane.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution from the hint above.

Here what I have done:

**1-** Insert new column next to the "TOTAL" column.
**2-** Use IF command for fail students i.e IF("rank"="F",0,value of "Total")
**3-** Now sort your sheet with adding levels according to your need.
**4-** Carry on with RANK or IF formula, which ever suits your requirement.